# How to render html page in node.js using http responce object?

Tags: node.js, http

this is my js file code:

```
fs.readFile(__dirname+'/product_list.html',function(error,productForm){
    if(error){
        response.write("error in getting file"+error);
    }else{
            connection.query("select * from products",function(err,result){
            if(err){
                console.log("In funciton errr");
            }else{
                response.writeHead(200, "OK", {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                response.write(productForm,{result:result});

                }
        });
    response.end();
    }
});
```

i want result on product_list.html page.....

Comment: you can use a template engine as `ejs` or other one it will be faster in this way and cleaner

Comment: i render on product_list.html page but...not getting result object on that page

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that `connection.query` is asynchronous, you should call `response.end()` within the callback function of `connection.query`

```
fs.readFile(__dirname+'/product_list.html',function(error,productForm){
    if(error){
        response.write("error in getting file"+error);
        response.end(); //finish here
    }else{
        connection.query("select * from products",function(err,result){
            if(err){
                console.log("In funciton errr");
                response.end(); //finish here
            }else{
                response.writeHead(200, "OK", {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
                response.write(productForm,{result:result});
                response.end(); //finish here
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: thank for answer.....after add this code...same problem is their..... render page but not getting result object in product_list.html page

Comment: what is `productForm` and `{result: result}`? are you using any template engine? then it should be `response.render(productForm, {result: result})`